# Retrieve last and next pattern after finding a pattern

Tags: c++, regex, shell, hashmap, pattern-matching

I've spent the last 2-3 days googling and searching a solution but I can't seem to find any.

Basically, I have a text file containing hundreds of thousands of records. Here's a pattern of what's contained in the file.

- Line 01: ^D 23554
- Line 02: Q 123 325
- Line 03: Y qwe325
- Line 04: ^P fiwkkwlds
- Line 05: Y qrwe
- Line 06: Y rtewt
- Line 07: ^A 284274  DFL  2939955 001
- Line 08: F 2739
- Line 09: ^D 23556
- Line 10: ^k 2994
- Line 11: ^A 284274  DFL  2939966 002
- Line 12: ^k 29942
- Line 13: ^k 32423
- Line 14: ^A 284274  DFL  2939957 003
- Line 15: F 23425
- Line 16: ^A 284274  DFL  2939958 004
- Line 17: F 92823
- Line 18: and so on...

Basically, there isn't a specific pattern in the data however every start of the line --> ^D, Q, Y, ^P, ^A, F, ^k represents a simple message.

I'm looking to create a script (preferably in shell, perl or c++) that will scan a file from the first line until the last line and

1) retrieve all the values in the ^A line
2) insert a delimiter
3) retrieve the last value in the ^D line
4) insert a delimiter
5) retrieve the next value in the F line
6) hopefully, create another text file with the data

Based on my previous example, below is the results:

- Line 01: 284274  DFL  2939955 001|23554|2739
- Line 02: 284274  DFL  2939966 002|23556|23425
- Line 03: 284274  DFL  2939957 003|23556|23425
- Line 04: 284274  DFL  2939958 004|23556|92823

In other words:

value from ^A line | value from previous ^D line | value from next F line.

Is there someone that could help me out? I've been reading about hashmaps and hashtables but I'm not too sure how to use them. I've seen a lot of solution using grep where you find a pattern ex: ^A and print the last x lines before/after that pattern however, as this data can be super random, the previous ^D message or next F message could be on any line.

The solution would kind of have to read the file and always keep in memory the ^D and F line value and retrieve them when pattern ^A is found.

Can someone help me out :)

Thank you!!!!

Comment: Show us your code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi Ibrahim. I didn't really write any code because I'm not to sure what to do. I did a few tests using grep to retrieve the content - in separate files - from the ^A, ^D and F line but nothing much. I was thinking about importing the files in an SQL database and try to find a solution, but I don't think that will help me a lot. Do you have any suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This one works, but i assume should be slow for big files:

```
IFS=$'\n'
readarray -t -O1 data< <(grep -h -e "\^D" -e "\^A" -e "^F" a.txt)
posA=1
for i in "${data[@]}"; do
if [[ "$i" = "^A"* ]]; then
    textA="${data[$posA]}"
    posD=$posA
    posF=$posA
    textD=""
    textF=""
    while [ "$posD" -ge 1 ] && [[ "$textD" != "^D"* ]]; do
    posD=$(($posD - 1))
    textD="${data[$posD]}"
    done

    while [ "$posF" -le "${#data[@]}" ] && [[ "$textF" != "F"* ]]; do
    posF=$(($posF + 1))
    textF="${data[$posF]}"
    done
    textADF="$textA | $textD | $textF"
    echo "ADF=$textADF"
fi
posA=$(($posA + 1))
done
unset IFS
exit
```

The whole implementations is based on the output of

```
grep -h -e "\^D" -e "\^A" -e "^F" a.txt
```

which is stored to an array "data" and then code manipulates this array, and also in the fact that while loop will stop in the first match.

Maybe you could combine above grep with head and tail to avoid array manipulation.

PS1: Applying also -n switch to grep provides an interesting output.

PS2: I was not capable to directly grep your file with groups of "^A ^D F" to avoid array manipulation with code, but may be this is possible with regex.

Comment: George, you are the man!!! This script works fine and it's quite fast to be honest. I tested it on my larger text file. Many thanks! You don't understand how much this helps. Really appreciate you efforts! Thumbs up!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pseudo code:

```
d_value = f_value = null
foreach line in input {
  if line matches ^A {
    print line | d_value | f_value
    d_value = f_value = null
  }
  else if line matches ^D
    a_value = <extracted value>
  else if line matches ^F
    f_value = <extracted value>
}
```

It assumes that d and f values precede a.  You can add error checking to make sure the values are present.

Hope you this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Regex:

```
(?<=\^A\s)(?<a>\V+)|(?<=\^D\s)(?<b>\V+)|(?<=\F\s)(?<c>\V+)
```

It captures `^A` value as group (a), `^D` value as group (b), and `F` value as group (c).

After matching these values, you can build easily on this Regex to sort them out with any programing language of your choice.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/2tipn0/1

Comment: Hi Ibrahim. I tried to use this regex with grep but I don't seem to know how to make it work. I tried grep -n '^\^A' file.txt but that retrieves the lines starting with ^A. I've also tried grep -n -C1 '^\^A' file.txt and that gives me the line before and after the pattern.